# Host is not running on when I am trying to connect to a docker image

Tags: docker, virtualbox, tensorflow, tls1.2

I am following the [tutorial of TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-installation) and setting up the docker image on my windows 7 machine.

I receive this message `Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running` message my Windows Command prompt tries to reach the docker images executed on VirtualBox.

### The steps

- I have [Docker 1.8 installed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) (latest version as we speak)

[image: Docker is up and running]

- I have VirtualBox v5.0.20 installed (latest)
- Docker is running correctly

### On the docker CLI

- I have create the vdocker image `docker-machine create vdocker -d virtualbox`

[image: result of the command: docker-machine ls]

- I run the command `eval $("C:\app\DockerToolbox\docker-machine.exe" env)`

### Under the windows command prompt

- I run `c:\ml\tensorflow>FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker-machine env --shell cmd vdocker') DO %i` and get the following error message `Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running`
- I run `docker-machine ls` command and I get timeouts

[image: docker-machine ls command generates timeouts]

---

What is the solution?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be this Docker issue:
https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/453